# How to create moving text using js inside EL expression

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a table with lots of text, I would like to use JavaScript to create a moving text within EL expression.

This is the part of table:

```
<o:dataTable id="productTable" value="#{produkty.produkty}" var="p">
    <o:column header="Opis" id="opisCol1" style="width: 350px;"
            sortingExpression="#{p.product.opis}">
    <f:facet name="subHeader">
         <o:inputTextFilter />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{p.product.description}"> <- in this place I would use js
    </h:outputText>
</o:datatable>
```

Text have to move horizontally, like quotation on the stock exchange, or the information bar at the bottom of the news screen.

Comment: marquee is back!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: i know this tag, but I want to move the text when I focus mouse on it, that's why I want to use js

Comment: And what html does that result in?

Comment: One of html generated cell:                                     `<td class="of_dynamicRule9" style="width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); border-right: medium none;">Kamera standardowa IP rodziny TruVision™ 1.3 MPx 1/3" Gen2,  Obudowa standardowa, Pełny tryb D/N, Mechaniczny filtr IR, H.264, PSIA/ONVIF, PoE / 12VDC, SDHC , PAL</td>`